# outlook settings for small screens

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The company "upgraded" my laptop a few weeks ago, and the new one has a very small screen -- 14", with a 1366x768 max resolution.  Outlook looks like crap -- I have to open each individual email to read it. (can't use preview pane)

Does anyone know of any Outlook settings that I can twiddle to make the most of this very limited display?

Comment: You are lacking some details for us to be much help to you. What brand and model of laptop? What version of Outlook? Are you looking to adjust the display? Or adjust Outlook?  What have you tried? Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: You might be able to adjust outlook a bit, but you will run into the same problem with many other programs. My usual solution to that is to close the laptop lid and only use regular monitors attached to the laptop. If you do not like plugging in  cables then ask for a docking station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapse the ribbon and use the vertical layout (preview pane in the bottom of the message list).